# Order of Operations - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone explain why c is equal to 25 and not 30? I keep getting 30 by multiplying a*(b//a) and then adding b to it after.

```
a=10
b=3*(a-5)
c=b+(b//a)*a
```

Comment: The order of operations is [documented in the expressions reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Comment: And `3 * (10 - 5)` is `15`, so `15 + (15 // 10) * 10` is `15 + (1) * 10` is `15 + 10`. That's [basic maths](https://www.mathsisfun.com/operation-order-bodmas.html), more than anything; multiplication before addition.

Comment: Because of math. Type `15 + (1 / 1) * 10` in any calculator and you will get 25. (I used `1 / 1` in order to still use division and get `1`)

Comment: Perhaps your confusion comes from the fact that `15 // 10` gives `1` and not `1.5`. If you change `//` to `/` you will get `30`.

Comment: remember the 'bodmas' rule. from left to right ->bracket of division,multiplication,addition, subtraction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it step by step and you'll see that you're doing

```
c = 15 + 1*10
```

Hence c is 25. b//a is floor division, meaning 15/10 becomes 1

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to understand whats going on is to print each steps:

```
a=10
b=3*(a-5)
print(b)
print(b//a)
print((b//a)*a)
print(b+(b//a)*a)
c=b+(b//a)*a
```

output

```
15
1
10
25
```

Answer (score 0):

`(15//10)` is equal to `1` so the formula for c is equivalent to `15+1*10` The `//` operator is floor division which round down to the nearest integer. In additon all the values you are using are integers. To get 30 you need to use the normal divsion operator `/` and case one of the operands in the division to a floating point number, like this: `c = b+(float(b)/a)*a` That code sets c to `30.0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
c = b + (b//a)*a = b + ((b//a)*a) = 15 + ((15//10)*10) = 15 + (1*10) = 25
```

Does this clear it up?

The crucial part is `15//10`, because `//` performs integer division which rounds down to the next integer. Note the difference between `/` and `//` in Python 3.

```
>>> 15/10
1.5
>>> 15//10
1
```